# Weak contraction

Tags: real-analysis

i'm looking for a characterization of a weak contraction, i.e $f:M\longrightarrow N$ is a weak contraction if $\forall x,y\in M$ $d_M(f(y),f(x))<d_N(y,x)$, Any body can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your definition looks like the only reasonable one to me.  If $M=N$ what you describe is known as a weak contraction.  I consulted http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping to see if the $M \neq N$ case has been done before (I'm sure ithas).  I couldn't find it exactly, but they do define "contraction" (not weak) between metric spaces.  Your definition looks like the only sensible combination of the ideas of weak contraction and contraction between two possibly different metric spaces.